# How to add powerline layer in open street map using leaflet js?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to add power lines in the map as a layer. I am using leaftlet for making this webapp. is there any possibility to add this info as a layer into the map. Or any example regarding this?

Comment: Do you already have the data / coordinates of your power lines, or do you need to retrieve them?

Comment: Actually I don't have any data at the moment. I have got a planetpower.osm and some other .osm files for different countries. I need to display them on leaflet map. But I have no idea how to do that :( . It would be nice if I have any json files with all those data. I am struggling for finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not trivial. The optimal solution will depend on the amount of data you are willing to process (i.e. do you need power lines for a small city, or for a whole continent?).

The process will probably involve extracting the power line data from a OSM planet dump (do read http://enipedia.tudelft.nl/wiki/Extracting_Power_Data_from_OpenStreetMap !), and then rendering that data as plain vector data (smaller sizes), raster tiles (backend work), or vector tiles (several approaches).

Comment: There are simpler solutions. You can for example just query [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and visualize the results on top of your Leaflet map. No planet dump involved, no manual rendering required.

Comment: Yeah, but the Overpass API query will be different depending on which kind of power lines or facilities to fetch, and there are [limits](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Limitations) to it (so it won't work for large areas)

Comment: That's correct. The Overpass API solution won't work for displaying a power line map of the whole world. It is only suited for small areas or when restricting the map to a high zoom level to reduce the amount of data that needs to be fetched.

Comment: Without having an idea of how much data the OP needs, it's difficult to say whether Overpass, or a planet dump extract, or maybe even a [Metro extract](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/), is better.

Comment: Thank you guys. For you discussion. I was able to extract geoJSON data from the "overpass-turbo.eu" . Just had to write some query in the wizard. But it was really hard to export data for big data set. Anyway finally it worked. Cheers!!!